# How to display images from local disk in mvc4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my MVC(4) application, I'm fetching the image files from the local directory and displaying it in the browser.

I've a `model` to store the details,and a `controller` to get the files and a `view` to display them.

**Model**

```
public class ImageModel
{
    List<string> _images = new List<string>();

    public ImageModel()
    {
        _images = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string> Images
    {
        get { return _images; }
        set { _images = value; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var imageFiles = new ImageModel();
    imageFiles.Images.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\mypath"));
    return View(imageFiles);
}
```

**View**

```
@for (int imgIndex = 0; imgIndex < Model.Images.Count; imgIndex++)
{
    <div >
      <img src = @Model.Images[imgIndex] alt="Image"  />
    </div>
}
```

But I can not view the images in the browser, its showing empty boxes with `alt`.

What did I miss here? Should I create a virtual directory instead of physical location.

Comment: Just look at the HTML and see where the image paths are pointing.

Answer (score 2):

First, local files require the [file:// URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme). You seem to use the native file path as img src.

But the browser security model forbids the use of local source from inside a page served by a web server (http://, https:// protocols).

To fix your situation, the implement a controller that take the desired image file name as parameter, and serve its content using the File() action.

Answer (score 0):

looking at the code snippet, it seems to me that you forgot to surround the path with quotes

```
<img src = "@Model.Images[imgIndex]" alt="Image"  />
```

but looking at the overall code, i would recommend to use relative paths.

UPD:
For a more detailed explanation, i would recomentd [this blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths)

Comment: @Anonymous are there any specific requirements for this implementation? why not just keep the files in the folder of an application to use relative paths. it might as well be a virtual directory if, for example you want to separate the image folder from the project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your path names.  This might help:
Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        var imageFiles = new ImageModel();
        imageFiles.Images.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\wherever\files\are\"));
        for (int i = 0; i < imageFiles.Images.Count; i++)
        {
            // get rid of the fully qualified path name
            imageFiles.Images[i] = imageFiles.Images[i].Replace(@"C:\wherever\files\are\", "");
            // change the slashes for web
            imageFiles.Images[i] = imageFiles.Images[i].Replace('\\','/');
        }
        return View(imageFiles);
}
```

View:

```
@for (int imgIndex = 0; imgIndex < Model.Images.Count; imgIndex++)
{
    <div >
      <img src = "@Model.Images[imgIndex]" /> <!-- put the file in quotes -->
    </div>
}
```